# Сусло и суслик - какая связь?

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Итак, читаем в Википедии про сусло: *"Это выжимка из винограда, содержащая смесь сахаров (глюкозы и фруктозы), кислот (винной, яблочной и т. д.), белковых, минеральных и слизистых веществ, а также ароматические вещества, придающие соку и вину присущий ему вкус. Виноградное сусло сбраживается под действием дрожжей (при этом сахар превращается в спирт). Конечным продуктом его брожения является вино"*. Суслик же, как известно, безобидный грызун, к вину и виноделию отношения не имеющий. Почему же они так похоже называются?

Answer (score 2):

Этимологически эти слова не связаны.

> **Сусло**
>   впервые др.-русск. сусло, 1419 г., согласно Востокову (у Желтова, ФЗ, 1876, вып. 6, стр. 50). Пытались установить родство с лит. šùsti, šuntù "тушить, варить", лтш. sust "тушиться (о еде); преть (о коже)", sàutêt "тушить, парить" (Миккола, Ursl. Gr. I, 160; Мél. Реdеrsеn 412). Принимая во внимание этимологию слова бра́га, можно считать более удачной мысль о происхождении из отглагольного имени др.-чув. *suslak, чув. sǝla, ср. тел., шорск. sus- "черпать, брать ложкой" (Рясянен, Toivonen-Festschrift 126 и сл.). Более сомнительно сближение с *sърǫ, *suti (см. сы́пать) (см. Желтов, ФЗ, 1876, вып. I, 51) или, наконец, с со́лод, сла́дкий (Горяев, ЭС 355). Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973

Т.е. этимологию слова сусло находят в названии процессов сбраживания, черпания и т.д.

> **суслик**
>        др.-русск. сусолъ – то же (Пов. врем. лет), болг. съ́сел "суслик, крыса", чеш., слвц. sysel, польск. suseɫ. Колебания вокализма первого слога, по-видимому, основаны на стар. отношении чередования. Вероятно, связано со звукоподражательным к. цслав. сысати "шипеть", болг. съ́скам "шиплю" (см. сыса́ла). Ср. лтш. susuris "серая или черная землеройка", susers "лесная мышь", д.-в.-н. sûsôn, sûsan "жужжать" (Штрекель, AfslPh 28, 516; М.–Э. 3, 1126 и сл.; Брюкнер 526; Голуб–Копечный 366). Другие предполагают связь с *sъsati (см. сосать), ссылаясь на блр. су́слiк "дитя, сосущее грудь", суслiць "сосать" (Ильинский, Jagić-Festschrift 293; Младенов 617). Более далеки в фонетическом отношении тюрк. слова: кыпч. sausar "куница", чагат., казах., тат. susar "Мustela sibirica", алт. suzar, монг. suusar, sausar, калм. sūsr̥ (Радлов 4, 782, 784, 786; Паасонен, FUF 2, 131; Сs. Sz. 121; Рамстедт, KWb. 339). Против заимств. из этого источника см. Мi. ТЕl. 2, 160. Сомнительно сравнение *susъlъ с др.-инд. c̨vásiti "свистит, шипит, вздыхает", вопреки Потебне, РФВ 4, 203. Сомнительно также сближение с названием раgus Siusli на Эльбе (Фульдские анналы 67 и сл.) у Первольфа (AfslPh 8, 5 и сл.). Ср.-в.-н. Zieselmaus "суслик" заимств. из слав.

Т.е. суслик образован или от слова-звукоподражания шипению, или от слова "сосать".

Как получилось что они похоже называются - случайно. Точно так же как кабачок, кабак и кабан.

Answer (score 1):

**СИСАЛЬ** . Это это название растения *агава* . Вот , выбрал цитату по словарям :"*Сизаль — (правильнее сисаль, по названию мексиканского порта Сисаль, Sisal на полуострове Юкатан) жёсткое, грубое натуральное волокно, получаемое из листьев агавы (См. Агава)(Agava sisolana); иногда С. называют само растение.*" *Большая советская энциклопедия* . В других словарях также отмечено , что словом **СИСАЛЬ**/**СИЗАЛЬ** называют и само растение *агава* . Оно завезено в Европу после открытия Америки Хр. Колумбом . У нас *агава* культивируется в парках Черноморского побережья Кавказа и Южного берега Крыма. Наиболее распространена *агава американская (Agave americana)*. Из листьев многих видов *агавы* изготавливают канаты, веревки, шпагат, упаковочные и грубые ткани; из отходов производят бумагу, главным образом оберточную. Некоторые виды агавы разводят в тропических областях обоих полушарий для получения волокна. Но есть и другая область применения агавы : из него **выжимают сок** , - можете посмотреть видео на YouTube , как это делается [Агава-чудо растение](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XBQVo7piUSM) . По другой интернет ссылке , - [Энциклопедия продуктов . Агава .](https://lady.mail.ru/product/agava/), - я прочитал : "*Сахаристый сок агавы часто используется в кулинарии. Сироп, приготовленный на основе сока агавы, служит отличным заменителем сахара. Аромат его напоминает мед с карамельным оттенком. Темный сироп агавы имеет более мягкий вкус патоки. Сироп из агавы добавляют во все виды выпечки, как самостоятельный компонент или в качестве заменителя сахара, меда, кленового сиропа. Сироп агавы не влияет на вкус и текстуру выпечки. Если нужно сохранить мягкость продукта, то сироп агавы подойдет идеально. Сироп агавы почти в два раза слаще сахара, поэтому это следует учитывать при приготовлении блюд. По текстуре он не очень густой, поэтому при приготовлении его можно добавлять по капле. Сироп агавы в чистом виде можно употреблять с вафлями и блинами, добавлять в разнообразные десерты, коктейли. Часто его добавляют в кофе или чай вместо сахара.*" . То есть , выходит , что **СУСЛО** это от **СИСАЛЬ** , а под последним могло пониматься как само растение , так и извлекаемый из него **сок** . Будучи преобразованным из **СИСАЛЬ** в **СУСЛО** , это последнее стало названием для выжимки из плодов винограда . У нас в Крыму местные забулдыги делают из этого виноградного **СУСЛА** , так называемую , *гурцулу* , - спиртной напиток индивидуально-личного производства . Я , когда ездил на уборку винограда , то не раз слышал , как виноградарша говорила таким же , как и я , горожанам , прибывшим на уборку за натур./оплату : "Увижу , что будете выжимать **сусло** ,  - выгоню с плантации !" . ////// Что касается слова **СУСЛИК** , то найти какие-либо корни этимологии мне не удалось . Ниже картинка : вот так выглядит растение **СИСАЛЬ** / АГАВА - [image: Агава]